# objectForKey stringValue crashing my app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, null, nsstring

I have a class that I use to setup objects in an array. In this class I have a custom "initWithDictionary", where I parse a `JSON` dictionary. However, as I am running into `NSNull`, this crashes my app. To get around this, I set up a class that handles exceptions, so when a string is `NSNull`, it's replace it with `@""`. or -1 for integers.

This is my NullExtensions class:

```
@interface NSNull (valueExtensions)

-(int)intValue;
-(NSString *)stringValue;

@end

@implementation NSNull (valueExtensions)

-(int)intValue {
    return -1;
}

-(NSString*)stringValue {
    return @"";
}

@end
```

However, in my initWithDictionary method, the following code crashes my app:

```
self.bookTitle = [[parsedDictionary objectForKey:@"book_title"] stringValue];
```

It doesn't work regardless of the object in the parsed dictionary being `NSNull` or containing a valid string. Only if I do the following (and the string is not null):

```
self.bookTitle = [parsedDictionary objectForKey:@"book_title"];
```

Is `stringValue` incorrect in this case? And if so, how do I use it properly in order to setup proper `NSNull` replacements?

Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of creating categories on `NSNull`, for which you would also have to add a similar category to `NSString` (that's why it crashes, because real strings do not respond to stringValue) - instead try creating a helper category on `NSDictionary` like "`stringForKey`" that uses the code Johan posted and returns an `NSString`, probably also should enforce all other types get mapped to empty strings as well.

Comment: Again -- don't do this. It will bite you eventually and, when it does, it'll be a total headscratcher.   If you are going to add such a method, prefix it.

Comment: To reinforce what bbum said: I’ve had a real-world problem where a -doubleValue category on NSDictionary caused a crash because a third-party input manager had a method of the same name but with different semantics. That one was fun.

Answer (score 6):

You really *really* don't want to add a category to NSNull that adds such common methods.  That will change the behavior of NSNull for *all* instances in the application, including ones created by the underlying frameworks solely for their private use.

If you need a value class that represents the notion of "value doesn't exist and therefore I'm going to return these default values instead", create a class or instance that represents exactly that.

As for why it crashes, I couldn't tell you without seeing the actual details of the crash.

---

And, yes, it really *is* **THAT** bad to add a category to a class that adds such a common method.  All it takes is one bit of code in a plug-in or framework that does:

```
if ([fooMaybeNull respondsToSelector: @selector(intValue)] bar = [fooMaybeNull intValue];
```

Not terribly farfetched -- I have had to debug nasty crashers or misbehaviors due to **exactly** this kind of willy-nilly category addition.

If you are going to add methods to a class via categories, **prefix your method names so as to isolate them from existing functionality**.  It is still fragile, but manageably so.

Comment: It's not THAT bad to create a category like this - it doesn't matter it exists for all other classes because they will never know about it to try calling!  Furthermore, it's not really practical to say he should create a new type because this is being returned by the JSON library - it's not really practical to modify the library to add a whole new type, when NSNull works perfectly well for what it does.

Comment: In any case, this is an abuse of categories. NSNull does not have a meaning 'stringValue' or 'intValue' in the general sense, so it shouldn't have such a method. Instead, the class dealing with this dictionary should be doing an 'obj == [NSNull null]' check rather than blindly sending message to objects of ambiguous types.

Comment: I have to disagree with bbum slightly. While I think you need to be judicious with your use of categories on Cocoa Touch classes—i.e., I don't think you should ever override existing methods—I don't think it's a big deal at all to add new functionality to existing classes. I make use of categories **heavily**, and I've never run into issues. It's just like the runtime, really: it's extremely easy to break things with so much flexibility, but responsible use of its features makes for greatly-enhanced application development.

Comment: @LucasTizma Your use of categories is about as close to maintainable as can be, but you also need to account for layering costs.   In porting some massive codebases from Cocoa to iOS, the categories on the Cocoa classes were a giant pain in the butt, for example.  You have to be very careful about injecting code in between system layers instead of being a client of those layers.   And, yes, with absolute discipline, they can be a useful tool.

Comment: @bbum Well, I've never written software for Cocoa, only iOS, so I have to defer to your experience on this one. But I imagine you have very good cause to offer this advice. :)

Answer (score 3):

You are asking an `NSString` for its `stringValue`. No need to convert a string to a string.

Try this:

```
if (![[parsedDictionary objectForKey:@"book_title"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
    self.bookTitle = [parsedDictionary objectForKey:@"book_title"];
} else {
    self.bookTitle = @"";
}
```

**Edit:** You should not use the category on `NSNull` you created. You don't need it, nor should you want it. If the source for the dictionary inserts `NSNull` instances, go ahead and use my code above. Normally you would expect to simple have no value inserted for the key, at which time you can simple see if `[parsedDictionary objectForKey:@"book_title"]` returns anything.

Comment: That doesn't make sense? self.bookTitle is the objectForKey:@"book_title". It's still get the value even it's a null and when I try to use the bookTitle string, it'll crash.

Comment: Ah, that's because you've inserted NSNull as an object in your dictionary, instead of simply omitting it. You can change the if statement to check wether the object is of class NSNull, than choose the right behavior.

Answer (score 3):

The NSNull extensions you have written look ok to me but using a method like stringValue may be confusing since other classes like NSNumber use this.

Personally though, I think NSNull replacement in this instance is unnecessary.  If you just made a quick test you can replace the NSNull where you need to. e.g.

```
id testObject = [parsedDictionary objectForKey:@"book_title"];
self.bookTitle = testObject==[NSNull null] ? @"" : testObject;
```

Comment: I think you have to test for `testObject==[NSNull null]` to properly identify the `NSNull` value. `NSNull` by itself is a Class, but the actual object stored in the dictionary would be the singleton instance `[NSNull null]`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the dictionary is returning `[NSNull null]`?  By default, dictionaries return `nil`, not `[NSNull null]`, when an value isn't found for a key.

Comment: Yes, it is NSNull - a JSON parser will use that to indicate a nil value as opposed to an empty string (which is different).

Answer (score 0):

> However, in my initWithDictionary method, the following code crashes my app:

```
self.bookTitle = [[parsedDictionary objectForKey:@"book_title"] stringValue];
```

> It doesn't work regardless of the object in the parsed dictionary being NSNull or containing a valid string.

That makes sense, since `stringValue` is not a valid method on `NSString`. It will work for `NSValue` and its subclasses, but not `NSString`.